# Mysql order by maximum length and then random single value

Tags: mysql

Here is table structure Table : callerid_data

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| callerid | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

[image]

I am looking for query output with single random number Which follow below conditions. Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a4038/1) for this question.

1. Check maximum matching prefix
2. Random value from matching prefix.

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM callerid_data WHERE (callerid LIKE '525525863252%' OR callerid LIKE '52552586325%' OR callerid LIKE '5255258632%' OR callerid LIKE '525525863%' OR callerid LIKE '52552586%' OR callerid LIKE '5255258%' OR callerid LIKE '525525%' OR callerid LIKE '52552%' OR callerid LIKE '5255%' OR callerid LIKE '525%' OR callerid LIKE '52%' OR callerid LIKE '5%' )   ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(callerid) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Current output :
This is taking any random number from entire table.

Expected output :
There should be only one random number from 3 possible value as outcome of above query.

```
   | 48 | 525511223301 |
   | 49 | 525511223335 |
   | 50 | 525511223376 |
```

Reason, 5255 is the maximum matching number for where condition ='525525863252'
And then one of them needs to be required choose.

Please let me know if you need any further details for this question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. Ordering by rand() is not optimum though.

Comment: @Starx For better clarification i just added limit 1 into above query.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question. But your question is not really that clear to understand, apparently I didn't understand it either. So that could be the reason behind it.

Anyways, I can see the answer below works for you, so I will move on.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM callerid_data 
ORDER BY (callerid LIKE '525525863252%')
        +(callerid LIKE '52552586325%')
        +(callerid LIKE '5255258632%')
        +(callerid LIKE '525525863%')
        +(callerid LIKE '52552586%')
        +(callerid LIKE '5255258%')
        +(callerid LIKE '525525%')
        +(callerid LIKE '52552%')
        +(callerid LIKE '5255%')
        +(callerid LIKE '525%')
        +(callerid LIKE '52%')
        +(callerid LIKE '5%') DESC, RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @AnkitDoshi I don't understand does this matches your need or I understand it wrongly?

Comment: It seems working as expected.